# Finding and removing outliers / anomalies in an array of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, anomaly-detection

I have an array of numbers like this in PHP:

```
$numbers = [
    0.0021030494216614,
    0.0019940179461615,
    0.0079320972662613,
    0.0040485829959514,
    0.0079320972662613,
    0.0021030494216614,
    0.0019940179461615,
    0.0079320972662613,
    0.0040485829959514,
    0.0079320972662613,
    0.0021030494216614,
    1.1002979145978,
    85.230769230769,
    6.5833333333333,
    0.015673981191223
];
```

In PHP, I am trying to find the outliers / anomalies in this array.

As you can see, the anomalies are

```
1.1002979145978,
85.230769230769,
6.5833333333333,
0.015673981191223
```

I am trying to find and remove the anomalies in any array.

Here is my code

```
function remove_anomalies($dataset, $magnitude = 1) {
    $count = count($dataset);
    $mean = array_sum($dataset) / $count;
    $deviation = sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $dataset, array_fill(0, $count, $mean))) / $count) * $magnitude;
        
    return array_filter($dataset, function($x) use ($mean, $deviation) { return ($x <= $mean + $deviation && $x >= $mean - $deviation); });
}
    
function sd_square($x, $mean) {
    return pow($x - $mean, 2);
}
```

However, when I put my array of `$numbers` in, it only gives me `[85.230769230769]` as the outlier when there are clearly more outliers there.
I have tried fiddling with the `$magnitude` and that did not improve anything.

Comment: Explain what make it an outlier so we don't have to reverse engineer all of your calculations.

Comment: Your standard deviation calculation appears to be correct, but none of the numbers other than 85.230769230769 is outside one standard deviation from the mean. Print out `$deviation` and you'll see it's 21.185657155859.

Comment: Also mean is "the value in the middle of the set", you've calculated the _average_. Even so, your outliers are so fantastically out of step with the rest of the data, and your data set is so small, as to throw off your standard deviation significantly. If you're looking for an algorithm to cherry-pick your data for you in this case it's probably going to be something with a logarithm in it. Or something as simple as lopping the top and bottom 5% of results off of the set.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm shown here uses mean absolute deviation (MAD) a robust measure to identify outliers.
All elements whose distance exceeds a multiple of the MAD are continuously removed and the MAD is recalculated.

```
  function median(array $data)
  {
    if(($count = count($data)) < 1) return false;
    sort($data, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $mid = (int)($count/2);
    if($count % 2) return $data[$mid];
    return  ($data[$mid] + $data[$mid-1])/2;
  }
  
  function mad(array $data)
  {
    if(($count = count($data)) < 1) return false;
    $median = median($data);
    $mad = 0.0;
    foreach($data as $xi) {
      $mad += abs($xi - $median);
    }
    return $mad/$count;
  }

  function cleanMedian(array &$data, $fac = 2.0)
  {
    do{
      $unsetCount = 0;
      $median = median($data);
      $mad = mad($data) * $fac;
      //remove all with diff > $mad
      foreach($data as $idx => $val){
        if(abs($val - $median) > $mad){
          unset($data[$idx]);
          ++$unsetCount;
        }
      }
    } while($unsetCount > 0);
  }
```

How to use:

```
$data = [
 //..
];
cleanMedian($data);
```

The parameter $fac needs to be experimented with depending on the data.
With the $ fac = 2 you get the desired result.

```
array (
  0 => 0.0021030494216614,
  1 => 0.0019940179461615,
  2 => 0.0079320972662613,
  3 => 0.0040485829959514,
  4 => 0.0079320972662613,
  5 => 0.0021030494216614,
  6 => 0.0019940179461615,
  7 => 0.0079320972662613,
  8 => 0.0040485829959514,
  9 => 0.0079320972662613,
  10 => 0.0021030494216614,
)
```

With fac = 4, the value 0.015673981191223 is included.