# Finding and removing only positive outliers in an array of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, anomaly-detection

This question is extending this
[old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895512/finding-and-removing-outliers-anomalies-in-an-array-of-numbers-in-php).

I have an array of numbers like this in PHP:

```
$numbers = [
    1.2,
    3.5,
    3.1,
    3.1,
    8.0,
    9.0
];
```

In PHP, I am trying to find the outliers in this highest end of this array.

As you can see, the anomalies are then

```
8.0,
9.0
```

So i do not want to remove

```
1.2
```

The old question finds outliers in both ends of the number series.
I am trying to find and remove the positive outliers in any array in PHP.

Comment: Looking at the previously provided algorithm, I think that you could not use `abs` and only remove items that are positively above the average.

Comment: @ChrisHaas You were absolutely correct.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - I can open a new question but since this question is so related I dare to ask it alongside. I have the situation where I want to do the exactly same but remove numbers from the lower end instead. So I want to keep 8.0 and 9.0 but remove 1.2. Is there a simple solution for that as well? Thanks again

Comment: Same as my previous comment, skip the `abs` and find the ones where the difference is negative. The point of `abs` is to hide the fact that a number could be on the low or hide end.

Comment: @ChrisHass you were right. I though had issues adjusting it with the factor to change the sensitivity. Thanks though since it answered the question.